# How to fold code with regex in NOTEPAD++ UDL v.2.1.0.12

Tags: notepad++, udl2

I'm adding a UDL for my special formatted test script in NOTEPAD++.
I'm trying to add folding to the code but it does not respond as expected.
My code's pattern is similar to XML format,  something like that:

```
[TEST DEFINITION]
    ...
[/TEST DEFINITION]

[TEST STEPS]
    [STEP 10]
        [STEP DEFINITION]
        ....
        [/STEP DEFINITION]
    [/STEP 10]

    [STEP 20]
        [STEP DEFINITION]
        ....
        [/STEP DEFINITION]
    [/STEP 20]
[/TEST STEPS]
```

I have tried putting:
`[STEP (DEFINITION,\d*)]`
for "Folding in code 1 style" -> "Open" input and

`[/STEP ([DEFINITION,\d*)]`
for "Folding in code 1 style" -> "Close" input.

But editor does not fold as expected instead it folds like random lines (or i do not understand the pattern it folds).
Any help?

[image: Example Image: When i delete both open and close folding patterns notepad++ can found the correct corresponding open-close tuples and draws a dotted line but there are not fold buttons for them]

Comment: UDL does not support regex.  Did you consult the link in the UDL dialog box: https://udl20.weebly.com/

Comment: I read it before working on this and even tried to find the Notepad++ parser script for "XML" because it's able to fold to corresponding custom opening that i can use too but failed to find any examples.